# Find Users with consecutive leaves

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to get a list of user who have leaves on 2 consecutive days in the last 30 days.

Table name: Attend
UserId, Date, Leave Flag

Leave flag is 'Y' for present and 'N' for a leave day.

Can this be done in SQL?

Thank you

Comment: You will find your get a better quality of answer and that people are more willing to help you if you are able to demonstrate that you have [tried something for yourself](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). This seems to be a recurring theme in your questions.

Comment: There are (at least) two basic approaches to queries like this. You can either do a self-join or a correlated subquery to look at data for both today and yesterday at the same time. (Fairly easy assuming yesterday can be found using Oracle date math, e.g., there aren't any complicated business logic rules that define yesterday). And of course, please follow @Ben's advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one leave per day and you are using a database that has window functions (which Oracle supports), then there is a trick you can use to avoid a self join.  It does require other processing.

The idea is that if we generate a sequence of numbers, ordered by the date for a user, then the difference between this sequence and the date will be constant.  For instance, if the dates are Mar 2, 4, 5, 7, then the sequence would be 1, 2, 3, 4 and the differences would be Mar 1, Mar 2, Mar 2, Mar 3.  We can then look at duplicates in this list.

The following query uses this approach:

```
select userid
from (select t.*, 
             dateadd(d, -seqnum, t.date) as diff
      from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by userid order by date) as seqnum
            from t
            where datediff(d, t.date, getdate()) <= 30 and leave = 'Y'
           ) t
     ) t
group by userid, diff
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.UserId FROM Attend AS a
INNER JOIN Attend AS b
ON a.UserId == b.UserId && a.LeaveFlag == 'N' && b.LeaveFlag == 'N' && 
DATEDIFF(dd,a.Date,b.Date) > 0 && a.Date < b.Date
WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, a.Date, GETDATE()) <= 30
```

The where clause may have to be modified depending on whether you want to include or exclude people who were away 31 and 30 days ago